# Remove duplicate xml elements and group nested elements by unique one

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am a very new xslt developer, thank you in advance for your understanding. I have the following xml document, which includes journals and their subscribers (subscriber names are in the attribute "identifier"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<journals xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    <journal name="00002030">
       <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>
    <journal name="00000372">
       <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>
    <journal name="00002030">
       <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>
    <journal name="00000372">
       <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
           </target>
        </journal>
    </journals>
```

I would like to create the document with unique journal elements, and, below them, their subscriber elements. The desired document would be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<journals xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    <journal name="00002030">
       <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
       <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>
    <journal name="00000372">
       <target identifier="aries" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
       <target identifier="cas" pubdate="01/01/2004">
          <targetLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
              xlink:href="targets.xml#xpointer(/descendant::subscriber[attribute::name='$subscriberNameFromDoc'])"/>
       </target>
    </journal>  
</journals>
```

Could you please suggest how to do that? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="journals"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="journals">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="journal" group-by="@name">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/target"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjinb